# Getting error of SpawnSync while creating a new project in ReactNative

Tags: react-native

I'm using Windows 7 with 64 bit, I have followed steps to install reactnative through [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) but while creating a new project I'm facing error
.

[image]